# How can I use "IS" keyword in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I'm converting `Oracle` stored procedure to `MYSQL`, in the following sql query how can use "IS" in mysql

```
CURSOR rout_acc_cursor
   IS
      (SELECT u06_exchange, u06_routing_ac_type,
              DECODE (u06_routing_ac_type,
                      0, u06_exchange_ac,
                      1
                     ) AS routing_ac,
              u06_commision_type, u06_commision_amt_small,
              u06_is_custodian_account, u06_commision_share, u06_txn_fee,
              u06_commision_group_id, -1 AS u06_cond_orders, u06_symbol_cond,
              0 AS u06_daydiscount, u06_trading_enabled
         FROM u06_routing_accounts
        WHERE u06_security_ac_id = sec_acc_id);

   cur_var                 rout_acc_cursor%ROWTYPE;
```

Comment: FYI, you'll also have to convert `DECODE` to `CASE`.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cursors.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Try in this way 


Declare rout_acc_cursor CURSOR For  SELECT u06_exchange, u06_routing_ac_type,
              DECODE (u06_routing_ac_type,
                      0, u06_exchange_ac,
                      1
                     ) AS routing_ac,
              u06_commision_type, u06_commision_amt_small,
              u06_is_custodian_account, u06_commision_share, u06_txn_fee,
              u06_commision_group_id, -1 AS u06_cond_orders, u06_symbol_cond,
              0 AS u06_daydiscount, u06_trading_enabled
         FROM u06_routing_accounts
        WHERE u06_security_ac_id = sec_acc_id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET HANDLER=1;
OPEN  rout_acc_cursor
MAINlOOP:LOOP

Fetch  rout_acc_cursor   into var1,VAR2......;
                      if HANDLER=1 THEN
                                 leave MAINloop;
                          close get_head_amount_CUR;

              END If;
END LOOP MAINlOOP
```